# SSAS 2017 - IF statement in calculated measure with condition from dim table

Tags: ssas-tabular

I am trying to get sum of fact table column based on dimension table column value. ie.

```
If Dim_Product[Origin]="A" 
THEN SUM(Fact_Connectivity[MONITOR_CNT]) 
ELSE 
SUM(Fact_Connectivity[TLA_MONITOR_CNT]).
```

I am using below formula:

```
Adoption %:= IF(Dim_Product[Origin]="A",
SUM(Fact_Connectivity[MONITOR_CNT]),
SUM(Fact_Connectivity[TLA_MONITOR_CNT]))
```

But I couldn't use Dim_Product[Origin] table fields in the formula even though Fact table has relationship with Dim table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly use it in a measure, raw, or using related, you will have to wrap it round with something to determine the row context.

So for example,

```
Measure = IF(MAX('Dim Origin'[Origin]) = "A"
          , SUM('Table'[Monitor_cnt])
          , SUM('Table'[TLA_Monitior_cnt])
          )
```

[image]

So on a row by row basis It will take the MAX value for that row, then apply the function. AS the row will only have one value the logic works.

You could also move this to a calculated column.

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried as suggested. Now for everything SUM(Monitor_cnt) coming even though Origin is not "A".